Not able to use AttachLinkObject in PDM with Python
Recently I started to try make automatically PowerDesigner Models with Python, because I am most familiar with language and I need to connect to database, transform data etc. I used win32com.client to execute PowerDesigner and I can successfully rename Model name, package name and Diagram name, then I am able to create task as specific stereotypes, fill them with the right data.
But the part where I am not able to continue is Links. One of my colleagues sent me their code they used in PD that works for them:
Set object1 = wfl_package.FindChildByName(rel_object1_name, cls_ExtendedObject)

But I am not able to access or I don't know how to access cls_ExtendedObject. So I tried different way to go, so I did this:
    # PD inicialization
    PD_App = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerDesigner.Application")
    PD_Model = PD_App.OpenModel(PD_Model_Path)

    Package = PD_Model.Packages.Item(0)
    Diagram = Package.PhysicalDiagrams.Item(0)

    # Link test
    start_task_link = Package.ExtendedLinks.CreateNew()
    start_task_link.Stereotype = 'Predecessor'
    start_task_link.Object1 = Package.Children.Item(0) # <- Getting the right object
    start_task_link.Object2 = Package.Children.Item(1) # <- Getting the also right object
    Diagram.AttachLinkObject(start_task_link)

But I am getting error:

TypeError: The Python instance cannot be converted to a COM object

I tried how will the generation look likes when I comment out the AttachLinkObject and I could see the link created between two tasks, but not visually visible... I also tried to initialize the library with different types, but unsuccessful :(
Would someone know what I am doing badly and should change?
Please if someone know, I would be very glad about help.

cls_ExtendedObject is a defined by an enum in the pdcommon Type Library, so it is possible that you can access it as PdCommon.cls_ExtendedObject. Ultimately it is just a numeric constant, 0x8af1c3d1, or -1963867183
It can be found in the sample/helper script Ole Automation\VBScriptConstants.vbs in PowerDesigner installation.

It could helpful to test the access to the OLE Automation API using a VBscript, executed using Tools > Execute Commands > Edit/Run Script inside PowerDesigner, before trying to do the same thing from another language. Besides it may give more helpful error messages.

Are the link extremities Package.Children.Item(0/1) already displayed in the diagram? PowerDesigner allows dragging a link from the Object Browser tree to an empty diagram, and create the 3 symbols: link and extremities.
I am not sure that AttachLinkObject does the same, and does not fail simply because the link extremities are not already displayed...

Hi @pascal,
Thanks for commenting on my post. I am not with my company notebook at the moment, but I will try it as you describe in the first comment and let you know. I know that the approach to do it from another language is not optimal, but the things that I need to do simultaneously before that are complicated for me and I would not be confident in another language other than Python, C# or little bit of Java.

To your last question, I will describe it so you know more context. I automatically create custom stereotype objects based on data (special stereotypes for our company) where I set object name, code, comment and our custom attributes etc. Then after everything is created and presented inside diagram I wanted to connect task based on data we have. But when I tried to do so, I get this error: TypeError: The Python instance cannot be converted to a COM object I think it might be related to something with Python and win32client library, so I will try it again tomorrow.

Thank you for commenting and trying to help me :)  @pascal
